# even a empty layout file is showing me inflate exception in android

Tags: android, xml, gridview

**The below is the layout file for activity main.The problem is  unable to start the activity since its showing some exception in the logcat.please help me to fix this.Initially when I had tried to display a grid view it showed this exception now also for a empty layout its showing the same exception I have no clue of what to do**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The below is my logcat**

```
2021-04-08 10:49:38.049 31158-31158/com.android.studymaterial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.studymaterial, PID: 31158
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.studymaterial/com.android.studymaterial.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #171 in com.android.studymaterial:layout/activity_main: row indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the row count. 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3956)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #171 in com.android.studymaterial:layout/activity_main: row indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the row count. 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: row indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the row count. 
    at android.widget.GridLayout.handleInvalidParams(GridLayout.java:855)
    at android.widget.GridLayout.checkLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:869)
    at android.widget.GridLayout.checkLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:886)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:6073)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5884)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5856)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
    at com.android.studymaterial.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8183)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8167)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3753)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3956)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var dept: Button
lateinit var aboutapp: Button
lateinit var announcements: Button
lateinit var clgwebsite:Button
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    dept = findViewById(R.id.btnDept)
    aboutapp = findViewById(R.id.btnAboutApp)
    announcements = findViewById(R.id.btnAnnouncement)
    clgwebsite=findViewById(R.id.btnClg)
    dept.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "clicked on dept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val startact = Intent(this@MainActivity, department::class.java)
        startActivity(startact)
        finish()
    }



    aboutapp.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "clicked on about app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val startact = Intent(this@MainActivity, Aboutapp::class.java)
        startActivity(startact)
        finish()
    }
    announcements.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "clicked on announcements", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val startact = Intent(this@MainActivity, Announcement::class.java)
        startActivity(startact)
        finish()

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try clearing the `build` folder or Invalidate Cache & Restart Android Studio

Comment: @Darshan how to clean the build folder sir

Comment: app directory > `build` folder > delete

Comment: @DarShan nothing is there in build folder

Comment: did you do Invalidate Cache & Restart Android Studio?
It is in the File menu in toolbar

Comment: @DarShan yes I did

Comment: Show your `MainActivity`

Comment: @Kaushik sir please check the question now I have added main activity code

Comment: Comment your onclicklisteners and findviewbyids' then clean and rebuild project

Comment: @Kaushik I tried sir still same problem

Comment: Comment everything only keep `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 }
}`

Comment: @Kaushik yes I did that only sir still same problem

Comment: Then create a fresh project

Comment: try to invalidate cache and restart then clean rebuild

Comment: activity_main - are you shure, that you editting this file?

Comment: @Yegorf yes sir